# CSS Dropdown menu shows up as horizontal instead of vertical

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to develop a website using django and I'd like to add a navigation bar dropdown menu, but for some reason, it keeps showing up as horizontal, instead of vertical.

I'm following the tutorial that W3 Schools has on their website https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_button

Despite all of my efforts it still doesn't work, I've tried to look at other questions, but most of them seem to be using a different method using lists, or their using a framework like react.

I moved my project over to this [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) and that just seemed to make the problem even worse, because now my second list item in the dropdown doesn't show up at all.

Here is the code I'm working with http://jsfiddle.net/iggy12345/ao04gfne/9/

Here is the code pasted below:

My html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <a class="active" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="/">Profile</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
            <a href="/">Customize Profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My css file:

```css
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    display: inline-block
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.header {
    background-color: #350752;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

.header > a, .dropdown > a {
    float: left;
    color: #dcb0f7;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.header a:hover {
    background-color: #15bccf;
    color: white;
}

.header a:active {
    background-color: #c7860e
    color: white;
}
```

## Edit

**I remodelled my css to look like Chaska's answer, but it still doesn't work, I had to make a few tweaks to get it to keep its original look, but now it adds a scrollbar whenever I hover over *profile*.**

Basically, according to the w3 tutorial, the dropdown list should show up **under** the *profile* box, but instead, whenever I try to do it, the entries just sit over the *profile* button, covering it up, and then on top of that, they continue *horizontally* instead of vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some revises applied to the css. Please read the relevant comment:

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 55px; /* overflow: hidden will hide the dropdown menu, use fixed height instead */
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px; /* must specify the top position */
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.header {
  background-color: #350752;
  overflow: visible; /* overflow: hidden will hide the dropdown menu */
}

.header > a, /* use > to select the direct child <a> instead of all of <a> child */
.dropdown > a {
  float: left;
  color: #dcb0f7;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #15bccf;
  color: white;
}

.header a:active {
  background-color: #c7860e;
  color: white;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <a class="active" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="/">Profile</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
            <a href="/">Customize Profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I remove the `overflow: hidden;` on the `.header`. Then the entire navbar disappears.

Comment: I remade my css to reflect your changes, but it still doesn't quite work, could you look at it again?

Comment: Okay. Try removing the `overflow: hidden;` from the header and then add `height: 55px;` to it.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.header{
  background-color: #350752;
  
}
.header a:hover {
  background-color: #15bccf;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="header"> 
 <a class="active" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
  </div>
<div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Try with this code with your CSS.

Comment: I removed the `.dropbtn` class because I don't want to try and make the button look exactly like the rest of the links in my navigation bar. Putting it back in isn't what I'm looking for.